# How machine learning libraries are created?

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to know how machine learning libraries (or in general libraries at large scale) are created. I mean Python doesn't have inbuilt array system but c has. So how they are supported for Python and how do they start the thing and develop it as we know today as a final product (like NumPy) ?

P.S.- Let me know if this is not the right community for asking general computing questions because there is significant overlap among CS stack exchange forums and if it's not right place then recommend the appropriate stack exchange platform for asking general computing questions.

Also, I couldn't find relevant tags so had to tag it with machine learning.

Comment: Numpy was available much before the deep network craze. It’s a wrapper to standard C libraries available decades ago.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What do you mean by, how were they created?  Someone implemented them.  I'm not sure what kind of answer you are expecting, or what information you are looking for.

Comment: But there are arrays in Python. Why do you say there's no in-built support?